# StringTemplates, how to create a group of templates in code

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4

I'm new to `StringTemplates` and try to figure out how to build a group of templates from a source other than files (it's actually in a database).

I miss something like (**pseudocode**):

```
STGroup group = new STGroup();
group.addTemplate("name", args, "... <actual template goes here> ...");
```

I wasn't able to find anything similar. `STGroup.defineTemplate`-methods all look like for internal use only or are java-doc'ed "for testing". `STGroup.compile` takes a `Token`.

I actually want to write the contents of a group file in Java. `STGroupString` doesn't look promising performance-wise. We have hundreds of templates, some of them very large. It doesn't make sense to me to render it into group file syntax and then let StringTemplates parse that back to a name, args, contents structure instead of directly passing in that structure.

Comment: What about `new ST("template body goes here")`? Where do name and args come from?

Comment: @Clashsoft: thanks, but this only creates a template, not a group. How is the template added to a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `STGroup.defineTemplate()`, even if its Javadoc says `for testing`:

```java
STGroup stGroup = new STGroup();

stGroup.defineTemplate("myTemplate", "is this true? <if (true)>yes<endif>");

// will print "is this true? yes"
System.out.println(stGroup.getInstanceOf("myTemplate").render());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess that would work. I switched to FreeMarker meanwhile, because StringTemplates are very poor from its API point of view (it actually doesn't have any abstraction, it's just a couple of classes that do plenty of things).